# Bitcoin : Edit CTxOut class in bitcoins source

Tags: bitcoin

Can we edit and add new field to CTxOut class in order to send additional information to transaction object and then to the blockchain?

Answer (score -1):

I got the following answer from [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/31972/how-to-add-additional-information-to-transaction)

Note that you should only do this, putting extra data into the block chain, if it is really necessary. The block chain has to be stored by every full node, so try not to take up all our hard drive space with unnecessary stuff whenever possible.

With that said, if you do want to add extra data to your transaction, then add an additional output to the transaction, for which the scriptPubKey has the following form:

```
OP_RETURN {80 bytes of whatever data you want}
```

80 bytes was chosen because it is big enough for a 64 byte hash and 16 other extra bytes of data, but not big enough to store anything maliciously big (like a movie collection). This transaction output is automatically un-spendable, and so will not be kept in the UTXO set in any pruning. The other UTXOs from your transaction will still be safe.